# Hadoop namenode failing to load fsimage

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I have issues with starting hdfs. My cluster is made of 3 nodes on google cloud platform. 1 is the active namenode. Node 2 is supposed to be a standby namenode and datanode. Node 3 is just datanode.

When I start hdfs my active namenode is up and running, but my standby namenode isn't, if I try to open the UI at node1:50070 everything looks great, but if I try node2:50070 it's not able to connect (site can't be reached). While checking the datanodes UI, when I open node2:50075 I see that namenode 1 is in RUNNING state while namenode 2 is CONNECTING (and it keeps being like that with heartbeat number rising forever).

It's quite funny because we have another testing environment with exactly the same hdfs configuration but we have no issue there.
Here below the log with the error:

```
2019-03-05 14:45:02,481 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage: Failed to load image from FSImageFile(file=/persist/hdfs/namenode/current/fsimage_0000000000000951913, cpktTxId=0000000000000951913)
java.io.IOException: Premature EOF from inputStream
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:208)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImageFormat$LoaderDelegator.load(FSImageFormat.java:220)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.loadFSImage(FSImage.java:931)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.loadFSImage(FSImage.java:915)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.loadFSImageFile(FSImage.java:788)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.loadFSImage(FSImage.java:718)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:316)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:1044)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:707)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:635)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:696)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:906)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:885)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1626)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1694)
2019-03-05 14:45:02,534 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: FSNamesystem write lock held for 12202 ms via
java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1559)
org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.getStackTrace(StringUtils.java:1033)
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystemLock.writeUnlock(FSNamesystemLock.java:252)
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.writeUnlock(FSNamesystem.java:1572)
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:1073)
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:707)
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:635)
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:696)
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:906)
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:885)
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1626)
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1694)
    Number of suppressed write-lock reports: 0
    Longest write-lock held interval: 12202
2019-03-05 14:45:02,535 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Encountered exception loading fsimage
java.io.IOException: Failed to load FSImage file, see error(s) above for more info.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.loadFSImage(FSImage.java:732)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:316)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:1044)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:707)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:635)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:696)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:906)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:885)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1626)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1694)
2019-03-05 14:45:02,555 INFO org.mortbay.log: Stopped HttpServer2$SelectChannelConnectorWithSafeStartup@core-acc2:50070
2019-03-05 14:45:02,563 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping NameNode metrics system...
2019-03-05 14:45:02,564 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system stopped.
2019-03-05 14:45:02,565 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system shutdown complete.
2019-03-05 14:45:02,565 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
java.io.IOException: Failed to load FSImage file, see error(s) above for more info.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.loadFSImage(FSImage.java:732)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:316)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:1044)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:707)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:635)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:696)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:906)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:885)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1626)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1694)
2019-03-05 14:45:02,568 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
2019-03-05 14:45:02,595 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at
```

(I truncated the log when copy-pasting).

As you can see, the error is clear, the namenode 2 is not able to load the fsimage. However, I'm not sure if the cause is only related to the fsimage itself or there is more, as I see an EOF exception and a write-lock held interval message that I haven't seen before.

What I noticed/tried:

1. I checked whether the fsimage was present and whether it was in the right directory, and yes the fsimage was there.
2. I noticed that the amount of edits_xxxxxx-xxxxxx in the hdfs/namenode/current directory of node 2 was really huge if compared with node 1, but I didn't touch any of the files.
3. I tried to copy the journal directory of node1 to replace the one in node 2, to see if a healthy journal could help, but it didn't work.
4. I tried to run hdfs namenode -recover but I practically got the same log output back.

I was reading somewhere that this could be due to a timeout or a number of threads produced by java, or sth like that, do you have any suggestion?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/49438/how-to-manually-checkpoint.html

Comment: It may not help with your issue but there is a patch to remove noise from logs when connecting continuously fails (IOException exception premature EOF) https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/HDFS-9572

Comment: And of course check space on the disk also if it has enough inodes  (df **-i**) but I asume  you did that.

Comment: Thank you guys, I'll try the suggested methods one by one and see if it works!